# Using Proof by Contradiction

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Use a proof by contradiction to show that if $n^3 + 1$ is odd, then $n$ is even for all integer $n$.

Given: $n^3 + 1$ is odd

Assume: $n$ is not even

I'm not sure where to go from here to prove this by contradiction.

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof by contradiction works this way.

Assume the negation of the sought conclusion; in your case, assume:

> $n$ is **not** *even*,

and derive a contradiction, i.e. derive a consequence contradicting the premise, in your case: $n^3+1$ is *odd*, or some other known fact.

A brute force check is: $n$ **not** even, i.e. odd, means $n=2k+1$, for some $k$.

Now compute $n^3+1=(2k+1)^3+1$ and find the contradiction with the premise.

Comment: So,

 n = 2k+1
n³+1 is odd

(2k+1)³+1
= 2k³+1+1 
= 2k³+2
This means that if k is even then the equation n³+1 would be even, right?

Comment: @JacobMcCullough - right conclusion with the **wrong** proof... The cube of the binomial is : $(a+b)^3=(a^3+3a^2b +3ab^2+b^3)$.

Comment: So is it (2k+1)³ = (2k³+3k²(1)+3k(1)²+(1)³)+1 = (2k³+3k²+3k)+1

Comment: It must be: $[(2k)^3+3(2k)^2+3(2k)+1^3]+1=2^3(k^3)+2^2(3k^2)+2(3k)+(1+1)$. All terms have a factor $2$ and thus they are **all** even.

Comment: Ok I see. I was not carrying the 2k over with every term. Thank you for clearing that up. I also now see that every term has a 2 in it, so it is even.

Answer (score 3):

Guide:

Suppose $n$ is not even, then it is odd. So you can express it as $n=2k+1$, now substitute this into $n^3+1$ to look for a contradiction.

If you know modulo arithmetic, the proof can be shorter.

Comment: So,

 n = 2k+1
n³+1 is odd

(2k+1)³+1
= 2k³+1+1 
= 2k³+2
This means that if k is even then the equation n³+1 would be even, right?

Comment: I'm not sure that $(2k+1)^3=2k^3+1$ ....

Comment: Thank you for your help Siong

Comment: $(2k+1)^3=(2k)^3+3(2k)^2+33(2k)+1$ by Binomial Theorem. Mauro is right. Somehow I just check that it is even.

Answer (score 2):

If n is not even, then $n$ and $n^3$ are odd, and $n^3+1$ is even (odd+odd=even). Contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Some detail more to better understand, not only intuitivelly why it works in general.

Note that from the logical point of view we are given

- $n^3+1$ odd $\implies n$ even

which is equivalent to

- $n^3+1$ even $\lor \, n$ even

thus the negation is

- $n^3+1$ odd $\land \, n$ odd

The proof by contradiction is made on the last showing that it is false from which follows that the original statement is true.

Comment: So,

 n = 2k+1
n³+1 is odd

(2k+1)³+1
= 2k³+1+1 
= 2k³+2
This means that if k is even then the equation n³+1 would be even, right?

Comment: Yes thus the negation is false and then the original statement is true. It is important that you get the logical framework which is a powerful tool for many proofs.

Comment: You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 1):

Why use contradiction, when using the contrapositive is so clear?

We want to prove

> If $n^3+1$ is odd, then $n$ is even

The contrapositive is

> If $n$ is not even, then $n^3+1$ is not odd

or, equivalently,

> If $n$ is odd, then $n^3+1$ is even

And this is clear because $n=2m+1$ implies $n^3+1=8 m^3 + 12 m^2 + 6 m + 2
$, an even number.

Nevertheless, a direct proof is also easy and can be based on $n^3+1 = (n+1)(n^2-n+1)$.